# How to optimize "Parse HTML" events?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

While profiling my webapp I noticed that my server is lighting fast and Chrome seems to be the bottleneck. I fired up Chrome's "timeline" developer tool and got the following numbers:

```
Total time: 523ms
Scripting: 369ms (70%)
```

I also ran a few `console.log(performance.now())` from the main Javascript file and the load time is actually closer to 700ms. This is pretty shocking for what I am rendering (an empty table and 2 buttons).

I continued my investigation by drilling into "Scripting":

```
Evaluating jQuery-min.js: 33ms
Evaluating jQuery-UI-min.js: 50ms
Evaluating raphael-min.js: 29ms
Evaluating content.js: 41ms
Evaluating jQuery.js: 12ms
Evaluating content.js: 19ms
GC Event: 63 ms
```

(I didn't list the smaller scripts but they accounted for the remaining time) I don't know what to make of this.

1. Are these numbers normal?
2. Where do I go from here? Are there other tools I should be running?
3. How do I optimize Parse HTML events?

Comment: [Uh… stop using slow libraries?](http://vanilla-js.com)

Comment: Why do you have jQuery included twice?

Comment: i like how jQuery executes 3X faster than jQuery-min... checkout yslow and follow its advice.

Comment: @bjb568 wow! Even with all features it's *still* only 25 bytes! Are there any similar libraries for document markup or webpage styling?!

Comment: @bjb568 "Slow" libraries for faster development time and less frustration - I'll take it! (As long as they really *do* help me be more productive and reduce my frustration - I have been able to find and fix the slow 3% of the code in all my project.)

Comment: @JustcallmeDrago That's called "vanilla CSS". Their website happens to be down right now, but I already downloaded the CSS file. Here it is:

Comment: @bjb568: Thank you so much this will revolutionize my web development.

Comment: @bjb568, excellent point. Does anyone document the "load cost" of popular libraries? Is there a tool for generating this information [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/) only touches upon one function at a time.

Comment: @Gili You can make a test yourself, shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @JustcallmeDrago: More like 33,000 bytes. You may want "all its features", but many others just don't find it and its massive performance hit worthwhile.

Comment: @cookiemonster We're talking about the [vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com), right?

Comment: @bjb568: I'm saying jQuery's size and speed issues makes it much less appealing than Vanilla. A few helper functions to smooth things over and maybe a dedicated polyfill for IE8, and it's a piece of cake.

Comment: @cookiemonster Yes, JustcallmeDrago was talking about how Vanilla JS gzipped is 25 bytes, how is 33,000 bytes relevant to this?

Comment: @bjb568: Oh, I thought he was saying jQuery was 25KB. My mistake.

Comment: @bjb568, as much as I am enjoying the sarcasm, I'm genuinely looking for solutions here. I don't mind using native JS functions myself, but I also want to use libraries like [Semantic-UI](http://semantic-ui.com/) and unfortunately they are built on top of jQuery, as are many other libraries. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: "Semantic", where you can use any tag with any semantic meaning for any UI element! WTH? Why don't you learn Javascript instead of relying on libraries (many of which are crap and slow, if you're lucky you get just slow or just crap) built upon more libraries (jQuery is both slow and crap)?

Comment: @bjb568, your tone is not constructive. 1. I am not an artist and as such I am not in the business of reinventing the wheel when it comes to UI. I'd like to save time by reusing interfaces that others have already created. 2. I use jQuery primarily to abstract way browser differences. Productivity was/is more important than performance. I'm open to moving off jQuery but I'm looking for an alternative that meets the aforementioned requirements.

Comment: @bjb568, PS: You should probably point people to http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ instead of badgering them. At least it provides alternatives :)

Comment: Hey look, you're the one who complained that things were too slow before complaining that you can't be bothered to make them fast on a site where both are off-topic.

Comment: I've got to agree with @bjb568 here. You seem to be asking for suggestions to improve performance, and then trying to avoid the one that'll actually make the most difference. WRT reinventing the wheel, that's what jQuery does. It's a slow API rewrite of a very usable fast API. The *youmightnotneedjquery.com* site isn't giving alternatives. It's giving the standard. jQuery is the "alternative". The suggestion to ditch the highly abstracted, highly generalized code libraries is about as good advice as you'll get IMO.

Comment: @cookiemonster, I don't have a problem with using straight JS but I'm worried about browser compatibility. Is there a thin library that will fill in that gap? Ideally, I want something that will fall through to native functions if they exist, or provide a shim if they are missing.

Comment: There are polyfills that will patch native methods. They'll work in IE8 and up, and you can conditionally load them so that only the browsers that need them will get them.

Comment: @cookiemonster, great. How about posting a new answer that explains that jQuery is slow to load and provides a list of such polyfills as an alternative?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For all the cynicism this question received, I am amused to discover they were all wrong.

I found Chrome's profiler output hard to interpret so I turned to `console.log(performance.now())`. This led me to discover that the page was taking 1400 ms to load the Javascript files, before I even invoke a single line of code!

This didn't make much sense, so revisited Chrome's Javascript profiler tool. The default sorting order `Heavy (Bottom Up)` didn't reveal anything meaningful, so I switched over to `Chart` mode. This revealed that many browser plugins were being loaded, and they were taking much longer to run than I had anticipated. So I disabled all plugins and reloaded the page. Guess what? The load time went down to 147ms.

That's right: **browser plugins were responsible for 90% of the load time!**

So to conclude:

- JQuery is substantially slower than native APIs, but this might be irrelevant in the grand scheme of things. This is why **good programmers use profilers to find bottlenecks**, as opposed to optimizing blindly. Don't trust people's subjective bias or a "gut feeling". Had I followed people's advise to optimize away JQuery it wouldn't have made a noticeable difference (I would have saved 100ms).
- The `timeline` tool doesn't report the correct total time. Skip the pretty graphs and use the following tools...
- Start simple. Use `console.log(performance.now())` to verify basic assumptions.
- Chrome's Javascript profiler

  - `Chart` will give you a chronological overview of the Javascript execution.
  - `Tree (Top Down)` will allow you to drill into methods, one level at a time.
- Turn off all browser plugins, restart the browser, and try again. You'd be surprised how much overhead some plugins contribute!

I hope this helps others.

PS: There is a nice article at http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-vs-raw-javascript-1-dom-forms/ which helps if you want to replace jQuery with the native APIs.

Comment: how did you swap to the Chart mode? I could not see that option

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo It looks like they changed the UI. The chronological overview of Javascript execution (what I called `Chart`) is now showing right above the window containing "Summary", "Bottom-Up", "Call Tree" and "Event Log". You don't need to enable it. It always shows.

Comment: This is why I always run performance tests using Chrome's Incognito Mode

Answer (score 3):

I think `Parse HTML` events happen every time you modify the inner HTML of an element, e.g.

```
$("#someiD").html(text);
```

A common style is to repeatedly append elements:

```
$.each(something, function() {
    $("#someTable").append("<tr>...</tr>");
});
```

This will parse the HTML for each row that's added. You can optimize this with:

```
var tablebody = '';
$.each(something, function() {
    tablebody += "<tr>...</tr>";
});
$("#someTable").html(tablebody);
```

Now it parses the entire thing at once, instead of repeatedly parsing it.

Comment: I don't think this applies to my case. I am getting this on a page where I am not modifying the DOM at all. That being said, I am using [Semantic-UI](http://semantic-ui.com/) and maybe it does. I get the feeling that most of the overhead is coming from initializing the jQuery library without actually using it to do anything yet.